# Static executable in Haskell depending on text-icu

Tags: haskell, static-linking, nix

I'm trying to create a static executable which depends on [text-icu](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu).

Here is the minified example https://github.com/4e6/text-icu-static-example

To enable static linking, I build `icu` with `--enable-static` flag [here](https://github.com/4e6/text-icu-static-example/blob/a1b5fb33fb508855617727375d82864819f42863/default.nix#L8-L16):

```
  # http://userguide.icu-project.org/packaging#TOC-Link-to-ICU-statically
  icu-static = pkgs.icu.overrideAttrs (attrs: {
    dontDisableStatic = true;
    configureFlags = (attrs.configureFlags or "") + " --enable-static";
    outputs = attrs.outputs ++ [ "static" ];
    postInstall = ''
      mkdir -p $static/lib
      mv -v lib/*.a $static/lib
    '' + (attrs.postInstall or "");
  });
```

And add following ghc options [here](https://github.com/4e6/text-icu-static-example/blob/a1b5fb33fb508855617727375d82864819f42863/default.nix#L27-L33):

```
    configureFlags = [
      "--ghc-option=-optl=-static"
      "--ghc-option=-optl=-pthread"
      "--ghc-option=-optl=-L${pkgs.glibc.static}/lib"
      "--ghc-option=-optl=-L${pkgs.gmp6.override { withStatic = true; }}/lib"
      "--ghc-option=-optl=-L${icu-static.static}/lib"
    ];
```

As a result of `nix-build .`, I'm getting a lot of errors about undefined references, see [nix-build.log](https://github.com/4e6/text-icu-static-example/blob/a1b5fb33fb508855617727375d82864819f42863/nix-build.log):

```
/nix/store/2h1il2pyfh20kc5rh7vnp5a564alxr21-icu4c-59.1-static/lib/libicui18n.a(regexcmp.ao):(.text+0x7805): more undefined references to `icu_59::UVector64::setElementAt(long, int)' follow
/nix/store/2h1il2pyfh20kc5rh7vnp5a564alxr21-icu4c-59.1-static/lib/libicui18n.a(regexcmp.ao): In function `icu_59::RegexCompile::compile(UText*, UParseError&, UErrorCode&)':
(.text+0x8355): undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length'
/nix/store/2h1il2pyfh20kc5rh7vnp5a564alxr21-icu4c-59.1-static/lib/libicui18n.a(regexcmp.ao):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN6icu_5912RegexCompileE[_ZTIN6icu_5912RegexCompileE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`cc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

This setup works with other libraries but fails with `text-icu`. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

link to [github issue](https://github.com/bos/text-icu/issues/39)

Comment: Have you tried compiling a small C program with the static ICU?  That might halve the places the problem is.  Are you passing `-DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION` somewhere?

Comment: I tried passing `-DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION` when compiling `text-icu` and test example, but it had no effect. AFAIK it should only matters when you include `icu` header files (I might be wrong here). I will try to build a static C program, it's a good idea, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Maybe the Haskell `text-icu` package needs `-DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION`?  I think something must include the `icu` headers.  [GHC docs on passing arguments to CPP](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#options-affecting-the-c-pre-processor)

Comment: Thank you for the link, I missed this piece somehow. I think I tried every option except `-optc-Dfoo` GHC flag. I feel this might be the case. I'll try it again this weekend

Comment: @bergey I was able to link a static C executable and then a Haskell one, but manually, using only GHC (Cabal still fails). TLDR, `-lstdc++` runtime required, and the order of libraries passed to linker matters. I described the whole process in the `4e6/text-icu-static-example` readme.